# Python can't run ANY script

Tags: python-2.7

I have Python 2.7.14 64-bit version installed and I can't run the simplest of scripts. It works normal if I copy to Shell and run from there. This is the script I'm trying to run.

```
def fun(a):
    print a
    return
```

And the error message

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1541, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\MultiCall.py", line 166, in handler
    r = l[i](event)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\ScriptBinding.py", line 149, in run_module_event

    if PyShell.use_subprocess:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'use_subprocess'
```

Comment: Seems like IDLE is broken, what if you try another IDE?

Comment: I tried uninstalling and installing different versions (2.7.9, 2.7.13), even 32-bit and still the same error.